# Entering non-active options.html file into Omnibar when debugging causes web search

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This my seem childish but I have not found anything with any search in this forum - a very basic thing.
I have no experience with the Chrome environment or webkit - mine is with IE. but here goes...

Following along with the getting started tutorials - is fine - got to Finnur's  using debug video link and ran into a confusing problem.  He states that to inspect items not currently active with an unpackaged extension that is loaded - you enter chrome-extensions://[extension id]/options.html in the omnibar.  The options.html file resides in the same folder as all other components dedicated to the extension.  The problem:  Every time I enter this info into the omnibar it brings up a web-search. through the preset default search engine. Cant seem to find a way to work offline or to turn off the search function.

So, I'm sure I am missing something very simple that all of your are very familiar with.  I am using all the "getting started" files and a copy of the options.html found there.  Options is grayed out in the drop-down menu of the extension but cant seem to load it.

```
 MANIFEST.JSON
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "options_page": "options.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

Very simple but cant seem to enter the options.html into the omnibar without having the search engine try to find it on the web and not in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The url should be `chrome-extension://[extension id]/options.html` not `` `chrome-extensions://[extension id]/options.html ``, notice theres no s at the end of extension in `chrome-extension://`.
Your manifest is a litlle malformed, the `options_page` shouldnt be in the `browser_action` field, try......

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ],
    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```